# Wix toolset MSI: Fail the installer when property value is not valid

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a MSI created using Wix

It has a property defined as below in `product.wxs` file

```
<Property Id="MY_FLAG">false</Property>
```

I will be calling my MSI from command line in the following ways

- `msiexec /i xyz.msi MY_FLAG=true`
- `msiexec /i xyz.msi`

I want my MSI to fail in case of invalid inputs such as

`msiexec /i xyz.msi MY_FLAG=sDGsgfdsf`

I want my installation to proceed only if someone passes `MY_FLAG` as true/false or not use `MY_FLAG` at all.

I want my MSI to fail if any other value apart from true/false is passed to `MY_FLAG`. The MSI should **fail** and not only abort. It should fail.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [LaunchConditions](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/launchconditions.html) action. It is checked early on in the install in the LaunchCondition action. This is the best practices way to do what you're attempting in an MSI.

Answer (score 0):

[Launch conditions](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/launchconditions.html) must be true or the setup is aborted. Here is a snippet you can try.

Launch a **`cmd.exe`** and pass in **`1`** or **`2`** or some other value to **`msiexec.exe`** and then in rapid sequence: **`inspect`**, **`observe`** & **`observations`**.

Sample command line: *`msiexec /i WiXLaunchConditionTest.msi MYFLAG=0`*

```
<!-- LAUNCH CONDITION -->

<Property Id="MYFLAG" Hidden="yes" Secure="yes">Wrong Value</Property>
<Condition Message="Value for MYFLAG must be 1 (true) or 0 (false)">
  <![CDATA[MYFLAG=0 OR MYFLAG=1]]>
</Condition>
```

Here is a whole sample for the above on [github.com](https://github.com):

- https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXLaunchConditionTest